# Display my HashSet to a listVIew

Tags: java, android, listview, hashset

I am trying to display my HashSet array to a ListView so that I can click on a cell and display an alert.

My code right now has three items within that HashSet array with the ability to add more items through an EditText that captures the user input and stores it in the HashSet.

I would like to know if there is a way to take the HashSet items and display them to a listview. I believe the list view allows me to click on a cell and display additional random info through an alert.

Is this even possible?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button aButton; // Global Scope
    Button sButton;
    TextView text2;
    EditText eText;
    HashSet<String> list = new HashSet<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_layout); 

        aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        text2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                list.add("Books");
                list.add("Newspapers");
                list.add("Magazines");
                String listString = "";

                for (String s : list) {
                    listString += s + " - ";
                }
                text2.setText(listString);
                }
            });




        sButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        eText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        sButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                 //Log.v("EditText", eText.getText().toString());
                 if( !list.add(eText.getText().toString()) )
                {
                     System.out.println("Not Unique Item");
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Saved!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Unique Entry Added");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved To Items.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }

        });


        }

    }
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a HashSet? Use ordinary ArrayList, create a ArrayAdapter and bind it to a ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with HashSet is sets by definition have no order, so it doesn't make much sense to allow direct coupling with a ListView. But it is easy to convert a HashSet into an ArrayList, like so:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(hashset);
```